# Jquery empty and live events

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to know if jquery empty kill all the live events.

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

I have a wizard which has various pops etc , I want to kill some live events and right now using jquery die

http://api.jquery.com/die/

My question is does jquery empty kill the live events by using die()

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.empty()` has no effect on events. The only way to remove `.live()` bound events is using `.die()`. You currently are doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Given that jQuery's API site seems down at the moment, I'm taking a fairly well-educated guess, but I understand that event handlers are essentially registered at DOM level, so just removing elements from the DOM will not affect the events registered against them.

Using a method like `$.die()` or `$.unbind()` is the best way to ensure those events are flushed.